# How can I change the style of the icons in a map with openlayer and a geoJson file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openlayers

I have an issue using react-openlayers. From a GeoJson file I'm trying to read the IconPath in features -> properties to be able to display every marker with its own icon in the map.

From Hiram Hackenbacker [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54326529/using-openlayers-how-can-i-display-different-icons-for-different-features-on-a/57595101#57595101),  I understand that I can use a predefined `function iconStyleFunc()`.
like this :

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,
    style: iconStyleFunc()
});
```

Do you know how I can use this function ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`iconStyleFunc` isn't predefined, `style` can set to any function which the developer defines, in that case it was called `iconStyleFunc`.  Unless the function always returns the same result `style` is set to the function, not the result of the function, i.e.

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,
    style: iconStyleFunc
});
```

In that question the feature had an `IconPath` property and the function created a style appropriate for that.  Instead of creating a new style on every call it is more efficient to cache styles based on properties used to create them.  See this example https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/igc.html

So an improved answer to the question on icon styles would be

```
var iconStyleCache = {};
function iconStyleFunc(feature) {

    var zIndex = 1;

    var iconName = feature.get("IconPath") || "pinother.png";
    var iconStyle = iconStyleCache[iconName];

    if (!iconStyle) {

      iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon(({
            anchor: [0.5, 36], 
            anchorXUnits: "fraction",
            anchorYUnits: "pixels",
            opacity: 1,
            src: "images/" + iconName,  
            zIndex: zIndex
        })),
        zIndex: zIndex
      });
      iconStyleCache[iconName] = iconStyle;

    }

    return iconStyle;

}
```